# Creating a New Firebase User - The Right Way

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

We have a huge update on Firebase and I struggle with auth system. I want to show alerts when a different error is met.

For now I have

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.createUserWithEmail(email, password: pwd) { (user, error) in

                    if let error = error {
                        print(error.localizedDescription)

                        if error.code == statusTooShortPassword {
                            Alert(title: "Error", message: "The password must be 6 characters long or more")
                                .showOkay()
                        } else if error.code == statusEmailInvalid {
                            Alert(title: "Error", message: "Invalid email. Try again")
                                .showOkay()
                        } else {
                            print(error)
                            Alert(title: "Error", message: "Try again")
                                .showOkay()
                        }

                    }
                }
```

But I have a strong feeling `error.code` isn't the best way to handle new user creation. I am looking at this part of the docs:

[image]

But I don't know how to implement `FIRAuthErrorCodeInvalidEmail` within `FIRAuth.auth()?.createUserWithEmail`

Can somebody please provide the right way of doing this, please?

UPDATE:
When email is in invalid format I get this:

```
Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17999 "An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x7fc3537ceca0 {Error Domain=FIRAuthInternalErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo={FIRAuthErrorUserInfoDeserializedResponseKey=<CFBasicHash 0x7fc3537d28c0 [0x1091b5a40]>{type = immutable dict, count = 3,
entries =>
    0 : <CFString 0x7fc3537c8c80 [0x1091b5a40]>{contents = "message"} = <CFString 0x7fc3537d2740 [0x1091b5a40]>{contents = "INVALID_EMAIL"}
    1 : errors = <CFArray 0x7fc3537ba570 [0x1091b5a40]>{type = immutable, count = 1, values = (
    0 : <CFBasicHash 0x7fc3537a9190 [0x1091b5a40]>{type = immutable dict, count = 3,
entries =>
    0 : reason = invalid
    1 : message = <CFString 0x7fc3537e7030 [0x1091b5a40]>{contents = "INVALID_EMAIL"}
    2 : domain = global
}

)}
    2 : code = <CFNumber 0xb000000000001903 [0x1091b5a40]>{value = +400, type = kCFNumberSInt64Type}
}
}}, error_name=ERROR_INTERNAL_ERROR, NSLocalizedDescription=An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information.}
```

My updated code:

```
if error.code == FIRAuthErrorCode.ErrorCodeInvalidEmail.rawValue {
                            Alert(title: "Error", message: "That is some funky email there. Try again")
                                .showOkay()
                        } else if error.code == FIRAuthErrorCode.ErrorCodeWeakPassword.rawValue {
                            Alert(title: "Error", message: "Password is too weak. Try 6 or more characters. Try again")
                                .showOkay()
                        } else {
                            print(error)
                        }
```

Answer (score 3):

I updated the answer to **Swift 3** syntax according to @user2462805

Try this

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser(withEmail: email, password: pwd) { (authResult, error) in
        if let error = error {

            if error._code == AuthErrorCode.invalidEmail.rawValue {
                //the error code goes here
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: That works, thanks. Only I have one more problem when an error with invalid email happens. It says "An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information." and I implemented code for that but it is not triggering.

Comment: seems like you are not the only one with that error https://iosprogramming.xyz/firebase-3-2-0-internal-error-on-create-user/

Comment: Well, that sucks. Now what, wait for Firebase to address this issue?

Comment: We are working on fixing this for the next release. For now, the workaround I'd recommend is to apply your own regex for detecting invalid email addresses on the client side.

Comment: @MazelTov This didn't work for me untill I did `if error._code == FIRAuthErrorCode.ErrorCodeInvalidEmail.rawValue`